# Google Cloud Messaging Push message limit

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

Is there a limit size about the quantity of push notification that we cand send to the devices monthly?

I have been reading the documentation but I can't find this information clearly.

This is very important for me because I want to developed an application for a client that allow them to send push notification to their user using the app.

Just in case could be useful: The app is a hybrid app built with Ionic.

I have been searching in here:

https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/

Maybe I am searching wrong.

The only information I found is the limit of message stored (100 per devices) the rest will be lost !

Comment: In google page : "Ask the GCM development community on Stack Overflow", that is the only resource about how to ask :/

Comment: Thanks ! I really appreciate the help

Comment: There is no limit as to how many messages you can send using GCM, you can find it [here](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/c2dm#history), it says "No quotas". However, there is a limit on message size depending on the type of message([notifications or data message](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/concept-options#payload)) that you are going to send.

Comment: This question isn't about programming related to Google Cloud Messaging, so it is off-topic for Stack Overflow. It may belong on [WebApps](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/).